# how to write a function that return the min, max value from array of data

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

i have seen a few solutions for this on google but none of them made sense to me, can   anyone explain in an easy straightforward way how to get the max or min value like   following situation?

e.g :
let say single product can supply by many suppliers

`1 . supp1 = 1000,1001,1002,1003  (productid's)`
`2 . supp2 = 1000,1002,1003`
`3 . supp3 = 1001,1003`

and i pass the 1 ,2 and 3 lists to some function and get two output  let say minQty and   maxQty
 e.g : 
`1000,1001,1002,1003 out put values 2 and 5`
`1000,1002,1003 out put values 6 and 3`
`1001,1003 out put values 4 and 9`

with above data 
i just want to find the min and max qty value for the selected product
output : `1000 = min 2  max 5`
        `1001 = min 2 max 9`
        `1002 = min 2 max 5`
        `1003 = min 2 max 9`

can anyone guide me how to achieve it with a code sample or logic
highly appreciate your help

Comment: your output values seem arbitrary and make no sense without more details. you should explain in more detail how the output values are calculated.

Comment: Mike, this is just a simple lookup - he's got the min and max in another array. I'm not sure why this is so tricky. Search the array for the value you are looking for and output the found value... I don't see the difficulty there.

Comment: I can understand that *min* means "how many suppliers have this product". However, what does *max* means? I'm not sure if this is a simple count problem

Answer (score 2):

In c# using linq.

```
public static Tuple<T, T> MaxAndMin<T>(IEnumerable<T> values)
{
   return new Tuple<T, T>(values.Max(), values.Min());
}
```

Explanation.  `T` is a generic type and `IEnumerable` will take any class that inherits it.  Linq `.Max` and `.Min` return the max and min respectively.  We return a tuple of the max and min.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays and List(Of T) have the ability to use the extension functions `.Min` and `.Max`. Then all you need to do is concatenate those together for your return string.

```
Dim myList As New List(Of Integer)
myList.Add(1)'etc

Dim min As Integer = myList.Min 
Dim max As Integer = myList.Max
```